# Spring MVC Hibernate Spring Security error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement Spring Security where I am getting the error.

UserAuthenticationProviderImpl.java

```
@Component(value = "authenticationProvider")
public class UserAuthenticationProviderImpl implements
        UserAuthenticationProvider {

    UserFunctionsService userFunctionsService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="userFunctionsService")
    public void setUserFunctionsService(UserFunctionsService userFunctionsService)
    {
        this.userFunctionsService = userFunctionsService;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.pir.authentication.UserAuthenticationProvider#authenticate(org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)
     */
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Users users = (Users) this.userFunctionsService.getUserDetails(authentication.getPrincipal().toString());

        if(users == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("Invalid credentials", authentication.getPrincipal()));

        String suppliedPasswordHash = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if(!users.getPassword().equals(suppliedPasswordHash)){
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid credentials");
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(users, users.getAuthorities());

        return token;
    }

}
```

Users.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

    @NotNull
    @Id
    @Column(name = "userID")
    private int userID;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Pattern(regexp = ".+@.+\\.[a-z]+")
    @Column(name = "emailID")
    private String emailID;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=3, max=50)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "mobileNo")
    private String mobileNo;


    @Column(name = "imageURL")
    private String imageURL;

    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="MM/dd/yyyy")
    @Column(name = "dateOfBirth")
    private String dateOfBirth;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "userType")
    private String userType;

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()
    {
        Set<UserAuthority> authority = new HashSet<UserAuthority>();

        return authority;
    }
}
```

UserAuthority

```
public class UserAuthority implements GrantedAuthority {

    private String authority;

    public UserAuthority(String authority)
    {
        this.authority = authority;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority#getAuthority()
     */

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return authority;
    }

}
```

Error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.pir.authentication.UserAuthenticationProviderImpl] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:287)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:461)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:512)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:506)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1523)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:34)
    org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.getObject(AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean.java:25)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1523)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:314)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:630)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:678)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

wel-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pir" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pir"
    p:username="root"
    p:password="user" />


    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_admin')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <security:form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            default-target-url="/index"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <security:csrf />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="userAuthenticationProviderImpl" class="com.pir.authentication.UserAuthenticationProviderImpl" />

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userAuthenticationProviderImpl" >
            <security:password-encoder hash="plaintext" />    
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bean you reference in `authentication-provider user-service-ref` must implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`. That interface contains only one method

```
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(java.lang.String username)
```

Your `UserAuthenticationProviderImpl` should just implement that interface and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implements either AuthenticationProvider interface or extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider  class if you want to write your own custom AuthenticationProvider. Can you post the code of UserAuthenticationProvider?

Comment: `UserAuthenticationProvider` is just an interface with authenticate method without body.

Comment: Instead of UserAuthenticationProvider implements spring AuthenticationProvider for customauthenitcation provider

Comment: It contains the method `supports`. Could you show me a tutorial, how to do this since I am new to spring security.

Comment: You can follow this example..https://aykutakin.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/spring-security-spring-custom-authentication-provider/

Comment: You can find many example on net..Also support method means which token this will support.You can take a look at this class default implemenation of spring AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java